# Is there a quantum operator associated with the momentum conjugate of theta in spherical coordinates?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

While studying the Schrodinger equation in three dimensions, I noted that there is a striking similarity laplacian operator and classical kinetic energy in polar coordinates:
$$
T = \frac{1}{2m}\left( p_r^2 + \frac{p_\theta^2}{r^2} + \frac{p_\phi^2}{r^2\sin^2 \theta} \right),
$$
$$
\nabla^2 = \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left( r^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \right) +\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{1}{\sin\theta} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\left( \sin \theta \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \right) + \frac{1}{r^2\sin^2 \theta}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \phi^2}.
$$
Here $p_r,p_\theta,p_\phi$ are the canonical momentum conjugate to $r,\theta,\phi$.

I was able to show that
$$
\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left( r^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \right) = \left(\frac{1}{r} + \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \right)^2, \ \ \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \phi^2} = \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi} \right)^2
$$
which leads me to believe that we can define the operators $\hat{p_r}$, $\hat{p_\phi}$ as
$$
\hat{p_r} = -i\hbar\left(\frac{1}{r} + \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right), \ \ \hat{p_\phi}  -i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}.
$$
Unfortunately I wasn't able to find the "square root" of the operator that involves derivative in $\theta$, and consequently couldn't find the operator $\hat{p_\theta}$. My question is therefore if there is such an operator.

I imagine that it would be very useful in the solution of problems in spherical coordinates because every eigenstate of $\hat{p_\theta}$ is also an eigenstate of $\hat{p_\theta}^2$, the former being much easier to find.